# Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DeepPartial<T>'

Tags: typescript, function, generics

I have the following code trying to create a generic function to abstract my repository infra to create a where clausule.

```js
export type DeepPartial<T> = T extends object
  ? {
    [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]>;
  }
  : T;

export interface SearchOneOptions<ENTITY extends { id: string }> {
  /** Names of object attributes nested in the result object that must be filled, if possible */
  includeNested?: string[];
  /** Entities that can be soft deleted won't appear in queries by default */
  withDeleted?: boolean;
  select?: string[];
  where?: DeepPartial<ENTITY>
}

const b = <T extends { id: string }>(t: T) => {
  const a: SearchOneOptions<T> = {
    where: {
      id: t.id
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm facing the following error
`Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DeepPartial<T>'.`

[Here is a playground to reproduce](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAixhgAoENYCWuANgDwAqAfHALxzlygzAB2AJgM5wQBGAVsADGMAFBw4AfjgBvMeLgBtbHAIs4Aa2CIIAM3oBdCQC50mHPhhEy5JfsoBuOQF85J8o5GhIsFS2ZQdXEFUAGVgfEEACwB5FmBosEsIFg5SAFEAOXIASXIATUYQZnYuaRU2Ew4YKFUAczgnallxAHoAKja4DNwAW2AuXW5%20IXhcGGqCHgBXZi44quA2XwRI1Ch%20qeJ4XgFhFbG4HqmquB5UHQJiYkWAGhU9SA4OSeu4Npa5VUFiKbZgDP6zDYxjgVRqLFqCn0jlaHTgaT8BEs-X28EEuDUZ1Bungf2uQLgAHdkgByUZgFD4ZYARymwBqKJ4iDgf0Cm3g7zkhKRkQw%20MWIJ4EAg1wxMNBwGuwhBYLqUPFhNW6xBGCweEIJHSWVyeUoIhcIkEyROPFocAohWKnBk5UqEwhDUoAAoYG4AJS0JpyI0pUYmMIRGJxBJJFIUah0ZryRX04AmKPyW0IAB0BDYcnELkz%20pEQA)

Do you know how to solve this error? Thank you very much :)

Comment: You don't need the conditional type: https://tsplay.dev/Wk81Lw This then breaks for function types but I don't think you need function types?

Comment: @zenly thank you for your answer! For the moment it has worked, I will thoroughly test it on Monday, do you mind adding it as an answer so I can give you credits ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional type in `DeepPartial` is not necessary since a mapped type on a primitive results in the original primitive value.

```
export type DeepPartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]>;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAixhgAoENYCWuANgDwAqAfHALxwDeAUHC3ANrZwEB2cA1sEQQAZnHIBdAPwAudJhz4YRMuQ7jKAbkYBfLY1CRYXbjGBRhuAMaoAysHyWAFgHluwZ2CURuAZ1IBRADlyAElyAE04UFNuABMfBi5Y2R8YKB4AczhtaiZWOAB3RzNgGTksPEISAOCw8M0dRkZLb1S4ACNaOAookBj4xIJkuFT07iycgAoYWXIASlpc5lYW33hcWTsHFzcPL18Kajo8-NYiktkT09Oh2RgAOiGAGmXr7Rf83R0tIA)